# Passing parameter value to javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass a parameter to my function but it does not get passed.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                function Person() {
                    alert('New Person Created');
                }
                Person.prototype.sayHello = function (parm1) {
                    alert('Hello from = ', parm1);
                };
                var itsme = new Person();
                itsme.sayHello('Prem');
                var newfunction = itsme.sayHello;
                newfunction.call(itsme);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery is useless here.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things going on.

- [`window.alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert) only displays the first argument, the others get ignored
  `window.alert(message);`
                            `^^^Accepts a single argument`
- You did only pass a `thisValue` to [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). You need to pass a string as second argument.
  `fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`
                                    `^^^ The string passed to sayHello`

---

```
function Person() {
    alert('New Person Created');
}
Person.prototype.sayHello = function (parm1) {
    alert('Hello from = ' + parm1);
    //                   ^^^ You should pass a single argument to alert, you can concatenate strings with a +
};

var itsme = new Person();
itsme.sayHello('Prem');
var newfunction = itsme.sayHello;
newfunction.call(itsme, "new function");
//                         ^^^ You weren't actually passing any parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with passing parameters; it's a simple matter of having a semantic error.  (Your console isn't showing it as a syntax error because you're allowed to pass extra parameters in to all JavaScript functions.)

`alert('Hello from = ', parm1);` is the issue.  `alert` only takes one argument, so use string concatentation.  If you instead use `alert('Hello from = ' + parm1)`, you should see the parameter is going through properly.

Comment: It's not a syntax error. `alert` is a function, functions can accept any number of arguments. `alert` just only uses arguments [0]. It's not like `if (arguments.length > 1) throw new SyntaxError ("...")`

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 Hey, MSG.  I'll stand by syntax error, since I explained why it's not throwing one.  It **is** still an error in the syntax of `alert`, even if the browser's compiler doesn't catch it.

Comment: Hey :) Still, the only points the [WebAPI specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#dom-alert) describes are 1. If the event loop's termination nesting level is non-zero, optionally abort these steps.    2. Release the storage mutex.     3. Optionally, abort these steps     4. Show the given `message` to the user. 5.Optionally, pause while waiting for the user to acknowledge the message.   I don't see where this should be an **error** in the syntax of alert.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 Well, the API doesn't convince me, but [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(programming_languages)#Syntax_versus_semantics) does.  I'll yield, it's a semantic error.